# Replacing develop branch with master

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

I have Master and Develop branches with remote tracking. I branch out develop into issue and feature branches and merge back into develop once the feature is done. Sometimes I might decide that the updates I merged into develop are actually not needed so I would like to "undo" the merge. Would it be ok to delete the develop branch and branch out again from master? or would this mess up the remote relationship?

Thanks

Comment: You could create a clone of your repository and try out if this works for you.

Comment: Everything you have published once should not be changed again; if you remove a branch and then create a new one with the same name that points to something else, it’s just like you would force push to the branch in the first place. And changing something that has been published once will mess up the remote and everyone who is working with it.

Answer (score 0):

The result depends on how much of the develop branch has been merged into master. There could be features that have not been propagated to master and hence would be lost if you decide to delete and recreate that branch.